# Get resource without reading it completely into memory

Tags: c#, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I have an application on the Compact Framework that has some large embedded resources (some of them are several megabytes).  I am calling `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(...)` which returns a `Stream` object.  However, I noticed that on some devices this call not only takes quite a while but causes the device to run out of available memory.  Eventually I used reflector to look at the code for this method on the compact framework and it uses an internal method to get a `byte[]` of the resource data.  It then returns this data wrapped in a `MemoryStream`.

Is there any way to retrieve a resource without using this call since it will always read everything into memory?  Ideally I'd like to work with a `Stream` that I can get random access to without having to read the whole thing into memory (similar to how a `FileStream` works).  It would be pretty neat if I could simply open a `FileStream` on the assembly and start reading at the appropriate offset, but I doubt this is how resources are embedded.

Comment: why do you have such large resources when you are targeting a device with limited memory?

Comment: I can easily use the resources on the limited memory devices without problem as I've been able to efficiently just use the pieces that I need on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an open source tool that exposes a lot of the assemblies meta meta and that allowed me to peak into the resource manually:
http://www.jbrowse.com/products/asmex/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an embedded resource.  Add it as a content file and open it off disk with a file stream.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really do this as this would impact the way the app is deployed.  It is actually a very simple app (single assembly exe).  I would need to have a separate installer to manage the individual content files.